# Inheritance in Java language

Tags: java, inheritance

We say that java follows a single inheritance model i.e. a Java class can extend only one class at max. and then say that every java class is inherited from Object class.

Suppose there are two classes A and B. Both A and B extend from Object. Now suppose A extends B. Doesn't it imply that A has multiple inheritence (A is inheriting from both B and Class Object)?

Comment: In short no, in single inheritance `Object` is a superclass (parent class) of `A` wich is a superclass of `B`. Multiple inheritance would be A extends Object, B extends Object, C extends A, B in which C has **two superclasses**. Read this(http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=28672&seqNum=12)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look at the difference between transitive inheritance (C inherits directly from B and transitively from A):

[image]

and multiple inheritance (C inheriting from both A and B):

[image]

Everything is just added on, except methods with the same signature, which are overridden. Even variables declared with the same name are added on, they're just said to be "hidden" but can still be accessed using casting, or the super keyword if it's the immediate parent.

Answer (score 3):

You can have an inheritance chain, this is not multiple inheritance.
You cannot have a class that inherits from more than one class **at a time**.

Forbidden by the language:

```
class A extends B, C
{}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Multiple Inheritance: (Not supported by Java)**

Class A extends Object

Class B extends Object

Class C extends A, B

```
 Object
   /\
  /  \
 /    \
A      B     (Not supported by Java)
 \     /
  \   /
   \ /
    C
```

**Multilevel/Transitive Inheritance:(Supported by Java)**

Class B extends Object

Class A extedns B

```
 Object
    |
    |
    |
    B        (Supported by Java)
    |
    |
    |
    A
```

Answer (score 1):

A Java class can only *directly* inherit from one class. In this case, `A` doesn't *directly* inherit from `Object`, only from `A`.

Are you solely asking from the perspective of terminology, or is there some *behaviour* you're interested in?

Answer (score 1):

Object A extends object B which extends Object. It's not multiple inheritance, it's hierarchy

Answer (score 1):

In Java, each class can **directly** extend only from **one** parent class. So, either B extends from Object and A extends from B, **xor** both A and B extend from Object.

You are supposing that both is true at the same time - this is not possible in Java.

If B extends from Object, and A extends from B, then yes, A does inherit from Object, but there is still a single parent to each and every class:

```
class Object
 |
 +-- class B
      |
      +-- class A
```

In other words, Java doesn't support multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

The main problems with multiple inheritance is the ambiguity, when two classes define the same method and are being both overriden and the [diamond problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem). Java doesn't suffer from this as, it allows overriding only a single class. This obviously refers to direct overriding and doesn't deal with hierarchies of inheritance. This kind of inheritance (A overring B, B overriding and so on) isn't affected by any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't let you extend more than 1 super-class. However, a class can implement multiple interfaces. You can create a structure of interfaces and abstract classes that let's you hack extending more than 1 class. Good luck!